# Delay in input change Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello I have an input in my application which fires on every stroke but I want some delay so for eg. trigger my search function after 1 sec so that it doesn't send multiple requests

**My Html Code**

```
<input id="musicsearch"
  (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)"  
  ng-model-options="{debounce:1000}" 
  class="form-control mr-sm-2"style="width: 100%;"
  type="text"placeholder="Search">
```

**component.ts (which handles change)**

```
 onSearchChange(searchValue : string ) {    
    this.router.navigate(['/search', searchValue]);      
  }
```

I am new to angular I can't find solution for my problem, I want to trigger this when user stop typing in input

Comment: maybe use (blur) instead of (input)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
  private modelChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  private subscription: Subscription;
  debounceTime = 500;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.modelChanged
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(this.debounceTime),
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.functionToBeCalled();
      });
  }
  functionToBeCalled() {
    console.log('Called After 500ms');
  }

  inputChanged() {
    this.modelChanged.next("Akshay Is Awesome")
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

html file 
`<input type="text" (keydown)="inputChanged()">`

Try This Thanks me later :)

Comment: @Akashay Cannot find name 'Subject'. , Cannot find name 'Subscription'. and  Cannot find name 'debounceTime'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.debounceTime'?

Comment: @SunilMeena,You need to import those.. If you look at the link i provided in my answer comment you will come to know..

Comment: import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

Hope This helps :)

Comment: error in import  => Module '"c:/xampp/htdocs/Angular/app/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported member 'Subscription'.

Comment: open your package.json and please let me know rxjs version

Comment: I've found if you use the (keyup) event you'll get all characters.  (keydown) was leaving off the last character for me.

Comment: Hi @Nate the event has been added just for reference purpose, we can use change, input, keydown or another valid event :)

Answer (score 8):

### On Html file

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchTxt" type="text" (keyup)="triggerSearch()">
```

### On ts file

```
searchTxt:string = '';
timeout = null;

triggerSearch() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.onSearchChange(this.searchTxt);
    }, 1000);
  }
```